# Cassandra CQL - NoSQL or SQL

Tags: sql, nosql, cassandra

I am pretty new to Cassandra, just started learning Cassandra a week ago.
I first read, that it was a NoSQL, but when i started using CQL,
I started to wonder whether Cassandra is a NoSQL or SQL DB?

***Can someone explain why CQL is more or less like SQL?***

Comment: can some one help with Syntax for, listing the total no of keyspace, column family in <cqlsh>... like show datadabases; show tables;

Comment: have given the solution for this to in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, CQL *is* SQL, so in the strictest sense Cassandra *is* an SQL database.  However, most people closely associate SQL with the [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) it is usually applied to.  Under this (mis)interpretation, Cassandra should not be considered an "SQL database" since it is not relational, and does not support [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

Comment: Yes but only in the barest minimum way; see my answer below.

Answer (score 48):

CQL is declarative like SQL and the very basic structure of the query component of the language (select things where condition) is the same.   But there are enough differences that one should not approach using it in the same way as conventional SQL.

The obvious items:  1.  There are no joins or subqueries. 2.  No transactions

Less obvious but equally important to note:

1. Except for the primary key, you can only apply a WHERE condition on a column if you have created an index on that column.  In SQL, you don't have to index a column to filter on it but in CQL the select statement will fail outright.
2. There are no OR or NOT logical operators, only AND.  It is very important to model your data so you won't need these two; it is very easy to accidentally forget.
3. Date handling is profoundly different.  CQL permits ONLY the equal operator for timestamps so extremely common and useful expressions like this do not work: `where dateField > TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')`   Also, CQL does not permit string insert of dates accurate to millis (seconds only) -- but it does permit entry of millis since epoch as a long int -- which most other DB engines do NOT permit.   Lastly, timezone (as GMT offset) is invisibly captured for both long millis and string formats without a timezone.  This can lead to confusion for those systems that deliberately do not conflate local time + GMT offset.
4. You can ONLY update a table based on primary key (or an IN list of primary keys).  You cannot update based on other column data, nor can you do a mass update like this: `update table set field = value;`  CQL demands a where clause with the primary key.
5. Grammar for AND does not permit parens.  TO be fair, it's not necessary because of the lack of the OR operator but this means traditional SQL rewriters that add "protective" parens around expressions will not work with CQL, e.g.: `select * from www where (str1 = 'foo2') and (dat1 = 12312442);`

In general, it is best to use Cassandra as a big, resilient permastore of data for which a small number of very high level, very high performance queries can be applied to drag out a subset of data to work with at the application layer.   That subset might be 1 million rows, yes.   CQL and the Cassandra model is not designed for 2 page long SELECT statements with embedded cases, aggregations, etc. etc.

Comment: Date handling is now possible in CQL3 as long as you have the timestamp as part of the compound key. This example explains it: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0

Comment: #3 is now possible in Casandra version 3 and more

Answer (score 5):

[Docs for CQLV3.0](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/index)

[CQL DESCRIBE](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/DESCRIBE) to get schema of `keyspace`, `column family`, `cluster`

CQL Doesn't support some stuffs I had known in SQL like `joins` `group by` `triggers` `cursors` `procedure` `transactions` `stored procedures`

CQL3.0 Supports [`ORDER BY`](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/SELECT)

CQL Supports all DML and DDL functionalities

CQL Supports `BATCH`

> ```
> BATCH is not an analogue for SQL ACID transactions.
> ```

Just the DOC mentioned above is a best reference :)